# Strange issue - Linux server unstable for some minutes (same) every hour - I need help identifying the issue

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I found the following issue really interesting, I think you will too.

I have a linux server that I use for hosting some websites. It uses CENTOS 6 and DIRECTADMIN. The websites have decent traffic, its a busy box, but I had never had instability issues.

The last few days something strange is happening.

Every hour, for some minutes, the same every time (26-30) the server is un-accessible by web.  The load is increasing a lot and a lot of httpd (apache) processes are opened.

I have done a very thorough analysis of the mod_status output, and I found nothing strange (I grouped ips with open connections). It seems that those are my normal traffic but for some reason are delayed.

top gives me nothing out of the ordinary, only the load is very increased, but no process stands out.

A lot (900 httpd processes are opened) but I haven't found any malicious ips that do a lot of requests. My best guess is that something is overloading the system and http queries are delayed.

I stopped crond and waited for the next cycle, the same happened.

I have also monitored port 80 with netstats grouping ips with open connections. Nothing unusual. nginx runs on port 80 and httpd on port 8000 and I check both, 8000 has connections only from my ip and port 80 no ip stands out.

/var/log/messages has NOTHING, apache error logs have nothing.

No crons running, and I get the same overload issue every hour like a clock. And after some minutes the storm passes.

Anyone has any ideas on how to pinpoint the issue ? Any other reason that CPU is consumed that doesn't show up on top ?

Comment: Well this sounds weired. Specially because your apache - logs don't say anything. I had an issue with spamers on my sites causing me to increase the number of max clients and servers due to a repeatly sending of term - signals to http - processes that did not exit. But this you would see in the httpd -logs. So obviously, if your client processes don't exit, this will increase the load of the server permanently.

Comment: One thin to check- Some web applications (e.g. Drupal) can be scheduled to run tasks at specific times without the use of cron.

Comment: Thanks sciurus. The websites on this server are custom coded from me and I always use crons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at external services that these apache processes connect to. Maybe you have a DB backup scheduled hourly at that time and maybe that locks all of the tables.

Overall it doesn't sound like a problem on the apache server itself.

Answer (score 1):

If it's that tightly scheduled, other than cross referencing all the logs for that period of time, you might consider attaching strace to the httpd PID for a more in depth look or running apache in debug mode in the foreground just before it usually occurs.

HTTPd has the -X option for that, though performance will obviously suffer so I would try to get as close to the event as possible.

"-X
    Run httpd in debug mode. Only one worker will be started and the server will not detach from the console."

For strace, you might try

```
strace -f -p $HTTPd_PID
```

and/or

```
strace -f -c -p $HTTPd_PID
```

-f to follow forks and -c to count the syscalls.